# Hard disk health indicator app

Tags: unity, hard-drive, indicator, system-monitor

Is there an app that can check hard disk health periodically, or an app that just runs in the background that will notify the user that the disk is nearing the end of its useful life?

Answer (score 5):

The app is already installed and is running in the background if you are using Ubuntu.

You can run "Disks" and see that the disk health is periodically checked.

If you click menu in the upper right corner, you can see SMART data.

If there is some problem, you will get a warning.

Comment: Got: Disks: command not found . Am I missing something else?

Comment: It is not a command. It is a GUI application. You can find it in Dash. The command is `gnome-disks` if you want to start it in CLI.

Comment: smart data and self test : is grayed out.. I guess its actively running in the background ?

Comment: Does it has a notification feature that gives a warning that a disk needs replacement?

Comment: Yes, it does... It may be grayed out if you selected some read-only media.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using smartmontools. 
I know this is not a unity app but a commandline tool, but it show you the disk health right now.

You can install it using `sudo apt-get install smartmontools` installed it with apt-get

you can run it using

```
sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda
```

This will run a test on the drive sda and print the results.

I hope it helps just a little :)